# Handling multiple exception using JUNIT5 test cases

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb, junit5, spring-boot-test

I have created a JUNIT test case for my DynamoDB CRUD operation. I have used assertions to handle the unexpected exception giver in below code.

```
@Test
void createItemsInTable() throws Exception {

    Assertions.assertThrows(UnexpectedException.class, () -> {

        ResponseEntity Res;

        CatalogItems cat = new CatalogItems(3, "", "fghsdfh");

        Res = Eservice.createItemInDynamoDbTable(cat);

        System.out.println(Res.getStatusCodeValue());

        CatalogItems cat2 = Eservice.findById("3");

        assertEquals(Res.getStatusCodeValue(), 201);

        assertEquals(cat2.getTitle(), cat.getTitle());

        assertEquals(cat2.getAuthor(), cat.getAuthor());

        assertEquals(cat2.getId(), cat.getId());

    });

}
```

How should i specify multiple exceptions in above JUNIT test case for ex: UnexpectedException, ResourceNotFoundException etc...

Comment: A single piece of code, ie the lambda expression, will only throw a single exception. So you should specify the one that you expect in that specific case. That said your code looks as though you wouldn’t expect an exception at all, why would you try to assert something otherwise?

Comment: Hi Johan, Thanks for the update, i have given the entire code for updating the item in AWS dynamoDb table. Kindly review my code and answer my queries?

Comment: In case of any clarification, Post ur comments. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd separate the three different scenarios into test cases of their own. Similar to that:

```java
@Test
void updateItem() throws Exception {
    CatalogItems cat = new CatalogItems(1, "xxxx", "f");

    ResponseEntity Res = Eservice.updateItemInDynamoDbTable(cat);

    System.out.println(Res.getStatusCodeValue());

    CatalogItems cat2 = Eservice.findById("1");

    assertEquals(Res.getStatusCodeValue(), 201);

    assertEquals(cat2.getAuthor(), cat.getAuthor());

    assertEquals(cat2.getTitle(), cat.getTitle());

    assertEquals(cat2.getId(), cat.getId());
}

@Test
void updateItemFailsWhenDestinationIsNotFound() {
    CatalogItems cat = new CatalogItems(3, "xxx", "xxx");

    Exception exception = assertThrows(ResourceNotFoundException.class, () -> {
        ResponseEntity Res = Eservice.updateItemInDynamoDbTable(cat);
    });

    String expectedMessage = "ResourceNotFoundException";

    String actualMessage = exception.getMessage();

    assertTrue(actualMessage.contains(expectedMessage));
}

@Test
void updateItemFailsWhenIdIsNotAvailableAtDestination() {
    CatalogItems cat = new CatalogItems(3, "xxx", "xxx");

    Exception exception = assertThrows(NullPointerException.class, () -> {
        ResponseEntity Res = Eservice.updateItemInDynamoDbTable(cat);
    });

    System.out.println(exception.getMessage());

    assertNull(exception.getMessage());
}
```

It's good practice to have only the code that actually throws the exception
in he assertThrows lambda. That way you can be sure it's this code that fails.

I'd also recommend to stick with Java's naming convention, i.e. have members, variables and parameters in lower camel case.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have given my code below for both positive and negative cases i have created a different set of code. while running test case i am commenting the unwanted code and running my text case. For Ex : if i have to test my positive test case i should comment negative test case and vice versa.

```
@Test
void updateItem() throws Exception {

    //Positive test case

    ResponseEntity Res;

    CatalogItems cat = new CatalogItems(1, "xxxx", "f");

    Res = Eservice.updateItemInDynamoDbTable(cat);

    System.out.println(Res.getStatusCodeValue());

    CatalogItems cat2 = Eservice.findById("1");

    assertEquals(Res.getStatusCodeValue(), 201);

    assertEquals(cat2.getAuthor(), cat.getAuthor());

    assertEquals(cat2.getTitle(), cat.getTitle());

    assertEquals(cat2.getId(), cat.getId());



    //Negative test case - if the destination is not found

        Exception exception = assertThrows(ResourceNotFoundException.class, () -> {

            ResponseEntity Res;

            CatalogItems cat = new CatalogItems(3, "xxx", "xxx");

            Res = Eservice.updateItemInDynamoDbTable(cat);

        });

        String expectedMessage = "ResourceNotFoundException";

        String actualMessage = exception.getMessage();

        assertTrue(actualMessage.contains(expectedMessage));



    //Negative test case for updating Id which is not available at destination

        Exception exception = assertThrows(NullPointerException.class, () -> {

            ResponseEntity Res;

            CatalogItems cat = new CatalogItems(3, "xxx", "xxx");

            Res = Eservice.updateItemInDynamoDbTable(cat);

        });

        System.out.println(exception.getMessage());

        assertNull(exception.getMessage());

}
```

Could you please confirm the way i am preparing and running test case is fine else have to change the way of testing?

Comment: I would extract the negative test case into a test method of its own. Apart from that it looks alright.

Comment: I would extract the negative test case into a test method of its own. Could you please  more specific about this statement?

Comment: It would be more helpful